# Haskell infinite list of Bernoulli distributed booleans

Tags: haskell, random

I need an list of biased, random booleans. Each boolean needs to have the same probability of being True (Bernoulli distributed). These booleans are passed to a function, which generates zero or more output booleans per input boolean. I need an infinite list, because I don't know in advance how many booleans are required to provide enough output. See the below (simplified) code:

```
import System.Random.MWC
import System.Random.MWC.Distributions

foo :: [Bool] -> [Bool] -- foo outputs zero or more Bools per input Bool

main = do
  gen <- create
  bits <- sequence . repeat $ bernoulli 0.25 gen
  print . take 32 . foo $ bits
```

Unfortunately, this code just hangs at the second line of `main`. I guess that there is something non-lazy happening somewhere with `Control.Monad.ST`?

(I would be able to do something like this with `System.Random.randoms`, but the resulting values don't have the required distributions.)

Can I fix this while keep using the `System.Random.MWC` library? Or does this require me to switch to alternative implementations?

Comment: This is the standard "building a list in a monad" problem. Monads force a certain kind of strictness on you some times. You can use a solution like `pipes`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mwc-random` package provides two `PrimMonad` instances, one for `IO` and another for `ST s`. As long as an `ST` computation is parameterized over all state tags `s`, we can run the computation and extract the value with [`runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST). By itself this wouldn't be very useful since we'd lose the state: the seed of the random generator, but mwc-random also provides explicit ways to [handle the seeds](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.3.0/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#t:Seed):

```
save :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> m Seed
restore :: PrimMonad m => Seed -> m (Gen (PrimState m))
```

We can use these to make a computation that generates a stream of values from a computation that generates a single value, as long as the generator is in `forall s. ST s`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import System.Random.MWC
import Control.Monad.ST
import System.Random.MWC.Distributions

randomStream :: forall s a. (forall s. GenST s -> ST s a) -> GenST s -> ST s [a]
randomStream item = go
    where
        go :: forall s. GenST s -> ST s [a]
        go gen = do
            x <- item gen
            seed <- save gen
            return (x:runST (restore seed >>= go))
```

With this we can write your example as

```
main = do
    bits <- withSystemRandom (randomStream (bernoulli 0.25))
    print . take 32 $ bits
```

We can actually build generators more sophisticated than using the same generator for each item in the stream. We could thread a state along the stream so that each value can depend on the results of the previous ones.

```
unfoldStream :: forall s a b. (forall s. b -> GenST s -> ST s (a, b)) -> b -> GenST s -> ST s [a]
unfoldStream item = go
    where
        go :: forall s. b -> GenST s -> ST s [a]
        go b gen = do
            (x,b') <- item b gen
            seed <- save gen
            return (x:runST (restore seed >>= go b'))
```

The following example stream has results that increase in likelihood every time the result is `False`.

```
import Control.Monad.Primitive

interesting :: (PrimMonad m) => Double -> Gen (PrimState m) -> m (Bool, Double)
interesting p gen = do
    result <- bernoulli p gen
    let p' = if result then p else p + (1-p)*0.25
    return (result, p')

main = do
    bits <- withSystemRandom (unfoldStream interesting 0)
    print . take 32 $ bits
```

Comment: For testing purposes it would be really useful to be able to use a fixed random seed (`initialize`) instead of the `withSystemRandom` function. I can't figure out how to alter the code to work with such a setup.

Comment: @Sebastian `create` and `initialize` make a `forall s. ST s (GenST s))`. You can apply a computation in the `forall s. ST s` monad with `>>=`, for example `create >>= unfoldStream interesting 0` or `initialize vector >>= randomStream (bernoulli 0.25)` (where `vector` is some vector you defined). In either case you will get an `forall s. ST s [Bool]` which you can run with `runST` to get just a `[Bool]`, for example `runST (initialize vector >>= randomStream (bernoulli 0.25))`.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was missing the runST and was just trying to extract the value from the Monad with `<-`.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is `sequence . repeat` - this will hang for (almost?) every monad, since you must perform a potentially infinite number of effects.

The simplest solutions would be to use a different library - which may not be possible if you are relying on the quality of the numbers produced from mwc-random. The next simplest solution is to rewrite `foo` to have type `[IO Bool] -> IO [Bool]` and pass it `repeat (bernoulli 0.25 gen)` - this would allow `foo` to make the choice of when to stop executing the effects produced by the infinite list. But having your logic inside of `IO` is not very nice.

The standard trick when you need an infinite list of random numbers is to use a pure function `f :: StdGen -> (Result, StdGen)`. Then `unfoldr (Just . f) :: StdGen -> [Result]`, and the output is an infinite list. At first glance, it may appear that mwc-random only has monadic functions, and that there is no pure interface. However, that is not the case, because `ST s` is an instance of `PrimMonad`. You also have the functions converting a `Gen` to a `Seed`. Using these, you can get a pure RNG function for any monadic one:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import System.Random.MWC
import System.Random.MWC.Distributions 
import Control.Monad.ST 
import Data.List 

pureRand :: (forall s . GenST s -> ST s t) -> Seed -> (t, Seed) 
pureRand f s = runST $ do 
  s'  <- restore s
  r   <- f s' 
  s'' <- save s' 
  return (r, s'')

pureBernoulli :: Double -> Seed -> (Bool, Seed)
pureBernoulli a = pureRand (bernoulli a) 

foo :: [Bool] -> [Bool]
foo = id 

main = do
  gen <- create >>= save
  let bits = unfoldr (Just . pureBernoulli 0.25) gen 
  print . take 32 . foo $ bits
```

It is unfortunate that mwc-random doesn't expose this sort of interface by default but it is pretty easy to get to.

The other option is slightly more scary - use unsafe functions.

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

repeatM rand = go where
  go = do
    x  <- rand
    xs <- unsafeInterleaveIO go
    return (x : xs)

main2 = do
  gen <- create
  bits <- repeatM (bernoulli 0.25 gen) 
  print . take 32 . foo $ bits
```

Naturally this comes with the usual caveats surrounding `unsafe` - use it only if you are exceedingly inconvenienced by the pure functions. `unsafeInterleaveIO` may reorder or never execute effects - if `foo`, for example, ignores one element, it will never be computed and the corresponding effect of updating the state stored in `gen` may not happen. For example, the following will print nothing:

```
snd <$> ((,) <$> unsafeInterleaveIO (putStrLn "Hello") <*> return ())
```